# Django rejects Requests' CSRF Token

Tags: python, django, csrf, python-requests

I'm writing an Ajax post with python's Request's library to a django backend

## Code:

```
import requests
import json
import sys

URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'

client = requests.session()

client.get(URL)

csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']


data = { 'file': "print \"It works!\"", 'fileName' : "JSONtest", 'fileExt':".py",'eDays':'99','eHours':'1', 'eMinutes':'1' }
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',  "X-CSRFToken":csrftoken}
r = requests.post(URL+"au", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Django gives me a 403 error stating that the CSRF token isn't set even though the request.META from csrf_failure() shows it is set. Is there something I'm missing or a stupid mistake I'm not catching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked my friend and he figured out the problem, basically you have to send the cookies that django gives you every time you do a request.

## corrected:

```
cookies = dict(client.cookies)
r = requests.post(URL+"au", data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,cookies=cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the referer to the headers, from the django docs:

> In addition, for HTTPS requests, strict referer checking is done by
>   CsrfViewMiddleware. This is necessary to address a Man-In-The-Middle
>   attack that is possible under HTTPS when using a session independent
>   nonce, due to the fact that HTTP ‘Set-Cookie’ headers are
>   (unfortunately) accepted by clients that are talking to a site under
>   HTTPS. (Referer checking is not done for HTTP requests because the
>   presence of the Referer header is not reliable enough under HTTP.)

so change this:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',  "X-CSRFToken":csrftoken, "Referer": URL}
```

Comment: I added the line, sadly it still doesn't work. It still gives me the "CSRF cookie not set." error.

Comment: Did you change the CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  setting? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-secure

Comment: Also try changing for `X-CSRFToken` for `csrfmiddlewaretoken`

Comment: Ya I checked all of those things, my friend answered helped me out on this one, I've posted the answer above. Thanks for your help anyways!